# mpmovieplayer - can I do an end run?

Tags: iphone, uiview, mpmovieplayer

I would like to be able to display a video on the iphone screen - preferably in a view so that I can control its display coordinates.  I want to be able to load the view and overlap and partially overlap a subview ...  is any of this feasible?  I have read that mpmovieplayer is the only method for video display (and is full screen)?  Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

You can place an overlay view on top of the video player, but that is pretty much it.  There is a sample application in the SDK that shows how to do this.

Comment: Yep - I've been researching - it looks like the player's capabilities are pretty rudimentary.  Thanks for the reply!